# Super simple double-opt-in subscriber management tool for maintaining an email list

Tags: email, mailing-list

After looking around all the other options for email distribution lists from various questions across this site, I cant seem to find something that isn't wildly overkill for what I need.

What I'm looking for is more akin to list-management so I can send updates for a project I am working on to a list of (currently) about 200 people. The only features I need right now are:

- Free, or very close to it.
- Keeps the subscribers list up to date with double-opt-in/out that I can set up with a "subscribe" form on the projects website, as well as an "unsubscribe" link that I can add to my emails.
- provides double-opt-in functionality to confirm subscriptions

The way I would plan to use such a system would be, whenever I want to send an email to the list (very infrequently), I would open the interface and copy the current comma-separated list of subscribers into the `BCC` Field of a new email (so they cant see each others addresses). Then I would write the email, making sure to include the "unsubscribe" link at the bottom (I'd likely put it in a signature or something). I'd then send the email.

That's pretty much all I'm looking for, just a simple tool to manage and maintain the list of people who subscribe or unsubscribe to getting updates on my project. It's such a low-volume, not super business-like thing at this point that I don't need all of the fancy drag-and-drop email builders

Comment: tbh I might just write one myself...

Comment: GNU Mailman (https://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/) also looks promising. looks like it can do double-opt-in https://itconnect.uw.edu/connect/email/resources/mailman/list-configuration-options/#subscription